# How about a tag wiki edit notification feature?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, global-inbox

Over on travel.se I'm pretty sure I'm currently the biggest editor of tag wikis (well excerpts anyway).

We have a few guidelines for style etc, like starting with a capital letter and ending with a full stop for uniformity and avoiding the word "is" and overly long excerpts because they can cause automatic truncation of the excerpt text in the Tags page which sometimes has ugly results. And of course things like avoiding literal definition of the tags.

For those of us with an interest in keeping the tag wikis in line with these goals there's no way to know when they've been edited other than suggested edits by low rep users, which are pretty rare on our site.

It would be great to add a notification system so that tag wiki edits would be announced in your "inbox".

It could work a couple of ways:

- Notify only tags I created or have previously edited.
- Notify only favourite tags.
- Opt in for notification of all tag edits on a site.
- Enable notification on each individual tag somehow.

Besides the inbox there could also be a tab very similar to the "active questions" tab for "active tag wikis" linked to the Tags page.

Comment: If your request is to be notified when a tag wiki changes so that you can lord over it or somehow own it, I'm not sure I'm in favor of such a feature.  The community belongs to everyone, not just to the people who make tag wikis.

Comment: Umm no what makes you think the motivation would have to be so negative? It would be good because good tag wikis are one factor in a good site. It could be made accessible only to moderators or as a high rep privilege for instance just like other features we already have that could be abused.

Answer (score 2):

Hallucinations from the icing say there used to be a page somewhere that listed recently changed or edited tag wikis.

That would be helpful in this request for information monitoring and less noisy for all the notifications with tag info pages being updated.

A tab you can go to would be preferable to inbox notifications. Unless you could also favourite tag repositories to signal explicitly wanting that kind of in-your-eyebrow notice.

There's a page that shows recently orphaned tag blobs, but nothing evidently visible for one tracking recent edits to these tag repos.