# There should be a way to review recent tag wiki edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Recently, several topics advocate using tag wikis for more than a cursory explanation of the tag:

- [Tag wikis need a size and functionality increase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122197/tag-wikis-need-a-size-and-functionality-increase)
- [Kill the book lists and put them home in their respective tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122121/kill-the-book-lists-and-put-them-home-in-their-respective-tag-wikis)

On SU, a similar issue is currently being implemented as an alternative to toplist questions:

- [Alternatives and the campfire lists are better in the tag wiki, within reason](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4372/alternatives-and-the-campfire-lists-are-better-in-the-tag-wiki-within-reason)

---

Given increased editing activity on the tag wikis, and possibly increasingly subjective content in them, the current ways for reviewing their content are really inadequate:

- Suggested edit review (one user's approval on SU)

For questions and answers, [edits that don't bump are bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers/26496#26496):

> Implementing any sort of "don't bump" functionality **would also delay accountability** and transparency for those edits.
>
> Notifying users of edits in the system allows them to take a look at the content and make sure there isn't something fishy going on. Imagine if people could make changes to the system without *anybody* noticing. **That is very exploitable.**

But **this is exactly the situation for tag wikis**. There is no front page where newly edited tag wikis show up for community review.

If a user is trusted or one of a tag's top users, there is no review possible at all, since the edit doesn't show up anywhere useful.

There's a list of *recently created tags* in the 10k tools, but it's very different and cannot be used for reviewing edits to tag wikis. The tags listed there usually have no tag wikis and very few associated questions. Additionally, it's completely redundant, given `/tags?tab=new`.

Tag wiki suggested edits and the decision are shown and linked to in the suggested edit statistics at `/tools/suggested-edits?tab=all`, but it's not possible to filter for tag wiki edits only, and it doesn't show edits by users with the privilege to edit without review.

### There is no effective community review of tag wiki edits.

We need something like the front page for tag wikis: **A list of recently edited tag wikis**, so that the community can actually review edits of *any* tag wiki.

[This topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116631/151367) is related, but has its focus on the inbox and actively notifying interested users, and requires some kind of opt-in. It's much more complicated to use (and probably also to implement) than just creating a list of recently edited wikis as part of `/review` or `/tags` that can be reviewed at will without prior commitment.

Comment: There used to be such a page, but apparently was too hoggy

Comment: @random I found a few references to that, but no explanations for the disappearance.

Comment: This seriously needs to be implemented. Since on SU it only takes **one** user to approve an edit, a lot of crap gets through, even with edits on "normal" posts.

Answer (score 7):

Agreed, the community is currently unable to provide oversight and accountability for the contents of tag wikis.

What would be useful would be

- A new “**active**” sorting option added to the existing **popular**, **name**, **new** options in the [Tags tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags). A view with the URL `/tags?tab=active`, similar to the [active questions view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions), that sorted the list of tags by most recent edit (to either its wiki or its excerpt) would be valuable.
- Giving 5k+ users (the [“approve tag wiki edits” moderation privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)) an inbox alert on any tag wiki change for tags they are high-scored in (perhaps silver badged) would make oversight more possible to exist.

Comment: −1: I think that wording would be confusing to users: many would think it means tags with post activity. (Nonetheless, I agree with the asker, above, that we need *something*.)

Comment: I'd think that would be quickly dispelled by the "edited [time ago]" linking to the tag wiki instead of a Q&A post.