# How to follow / get a notification from tag wikis edits

Tags: support, edits, notifications, tag-wiki

As of 2022, is there a way to follow / watch / subscribe to a tag wiki or to filter suggested edits to only view suggested edits for a specific case, i.e., [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground)?

---

There are some old [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) related to tag wiki edits:

- [How about a tag wiki edit notification feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116631/289691), from 2011.
- [There should be a way to review recent tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122521/289691), from 2012.

There are also some old [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) asking for review queue for tag wiki edits:

- [Create a separate review queue for tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165254/289691), from 2013.
- [Can we have tag wiki and wiki excerpt edit reviews in a separate queue to suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277031/289691), from 2016.

Let’s say that interested in [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground). I know that there are already several features to help find the activity around this tag:

- Tag watching
- Filter views
- Saves
- Follow specific questions and answers

Here [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground) has only one question here, but it's very likely that there will be more in the future and that the tag wiki eventually will be edited (I just made a suggested edit for this tag). On other sites I have participated in editing some tag wikis, one them is being edited as part of a currently active collaborative effort to build a tag FAQ. I would like to get a notification when any edit is done to the tag wikis of a few tags; some of them I already edited, others not.

Comment: I requested the [tag wiki filter for the suggested edits review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363361) during the review queue redesign. I guess it didn't get much support because there was so much going on back then. But I think this would help unclog the suggested edits review queue on SO because only 5k reviewers get to see those suggestions and many of them take over 1 month  to be reviewed. (Reviewing tag wikis also requires a completely different mindset from reviewing posts.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks that at this time it's not possible by using the built-in features, but it might be possible by creating a Stack App / using the [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Related posts from Stacks Apps

- [List recent tag wiki edits](https://stackapps.com/q/6483/37421)

  - It has only one answer, suggesting the use of SEDE providing a query code example-
- [How to get "usage guidance" for a tag from the Stack Exchange API?](https://stackapps.com/q/8503/37421)
- [How to get all tags' descriptions from the Stack Exchange API directly?](https://stackapps.com/q/8835/37421)